# Go Lang, Postgres: cannot get oid after Scan

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

I have 2 columns if table `accounts`:

`oid` and `balance`

By the next code I try to extract `oid` then `balance`:

```
// variable `id` comes from an another part

sqlstr := `SELECT * ` +
    `FROM accounts ` +
    `WHERE oid=` + id + `;`

q, err := db.Query(sqlstr)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: GetAccount \n", err)
    return Account{}, err
}
defer q.Close()


var _id string
var bal float64

q.Next()
q.Scan(&_id)
fmt.Println("_id ", _id)


q.Next()
q.Scan(&bal)
fmt.Println("bal ", bal)
```

After the first `q.Next()` I expected to extract `oid` and after the second to extract `balance`.

But every time after the first `q.Next()` and after the second I only get `balance`.

I tried to change `sqlstr` to the next:

```
sqlstr := `SELECT oid, balance ` +
    `FROM accounts ` +
    `WHERE oid=` + id + `;`
```

But I still cannot extract oid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `q.Scan(&_id, &bal)`, [func (*Row) Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row.Scan) has this signature:

```
func (r *Row) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
```

It expects the the pointers to the values where it will store the queried data.

If you are only querying for a single row, there is [func (*DB) QueryRow()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow). Then your code will simplify to

```
row := db.QueryRow(sqlstr)
err := row.Scan(&_id, &bal)
// err will be sql.ErrNoRows if no rows have been selected
```

Comment: It says: `sql: expected 1 destination arguments in Scan, not 2`

Comment: What exact PG library are you using? Is it this one: https://github.com/lib/pq? How are you opening your database connection?

Comment: Are you opening your DB connection like this: `db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)`?

Comment: I use `github.com/lib/pq` as DB driver, but to connect DB I use `github.com/xo/dburl`

Comment: Can you post how you are opening your database connection?

Comment: to connect DB I use this: `db, err := dburl.Open("pgsql://user:pass@host/dbname?sslmode=disable")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183559/discussion-between-ssemilla-and-alex-chaliy).

Comment: So **the solution is** to use `oid, balance` instead of `*` in sql query string, to use `db.QueryRow()` instead of `db.Query()`, and to use `row.Scan(&_id, &bal)` according to `oid, balance` in sql query string.